# How to drag and drop images in the grid adjusting their positions in react native

Tags: react-native, react-native-animatable

[image: drag and drop in the grid]

I want to achieve the above drag and drop functionality in the grid, where images are also adjusting the position according to the sequence, images should be redraggable, so that they can be put in another column. I have explored a npm package https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-draggable-grid so far. It offers a grid but how can I drag a particular image in the grid and it catches it.